# Eclipse Scout Neon hide settings icon on table field

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-scout

I would like to know how to hide settings wheel icon in header of table field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: At the time of writing, Eclipse Scout Neon is not yet released.*

From browsing the source code I did not see a convenient *getConfigured...* method to quickly hide that menu.

Fear not, you have two options to do so anyway. 
The menu you wish to get rid of is the [OrganizeColumnsMenu](https://github.com/eclipse/scout.rt/blob/releases/6.0.x/org.eclipse.scout.rt.client/src/main/java/org/eclipse/scout/rt/client/ui/basic/table/menus/OrganizeColumnsMenu.java).

1. Override `execInitTable` on your table and hide the menu:

   `getMenuByClass(OrganizeColumnsMenu.class).setVisibleGranted(false);`
2. Alternatively, override `addHeaderMenus(OrderedCollection<IMenu> menus)` and either remove the menu added by the default implementation, or not call the super implementation at all.